# $(a-3)^3+(b-2)^3+(c-2)^3=0$, $a+b+c=2$, $a^2+b^2+c^2=6$. Prove that at least one from $a,b,c$ is 2.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Assume that $\{a,b,c\} \subset \Bbb R$, $(a-3)^3+(b-2)^3+(c-2)^3=0$, $a+b+c=2$, $a^2+b^2+c^2=6$.
>
> Prove that at least one of the numbers $a, b, c\ $ is 2.

This is from a list of problems used for training a team for a math olympics. I tried to use known Newton identities and other symmetric polynomial results but without success (perhaps a wrong approach). Sorry if it is a duplicate. Hints and answers are always welcomed.

**Edit:** There is a problem with the original statement of the question in the original source. Under these assumptions it is impossible to have $a, b, c$ with value 2, as spotted in the comments and proved by the answers below

Comment: The first summand is meant to be $(a-3)^3$, not $(a-2)^3$? Or maybe they should all feature $-3$...

Comment: @Mr.Chip This is correct (as in the original statement). There was a typo in the $a+b+c=0$ condition. That is actually $a+b+c=2$. I've already fixed this.

Comment: Well, I've just plotted $(x-3)^3 + (y-2)^3 + (z-2)^3 = 0$ and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 6$, and the graphs are disjoint... In the sense that falsehood implies anything, your conclusion is correct, but that's not very satisfying.

Comment: Are you perhaps missing a $6^2$?

Comment: @Mr.Chip There is always a possibility that the original statement has a typo.

Comment: I think it has to. It's awfully asymmetric for there to be a (symmetric) conclusion of the form "one of $a, b, c$ is 2".

Comment: Inicdentally, the assumption that one of $a,b,c$ is $2$ leads to contradictions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $a=2$. Then $b+c=0$ and hence $b=-c$. The third equation gives $b^2+c^2=2$ hence $2b^2=2$ and $b^2=1$. If $b=1$ then $c=-1$ and vice versa. Then $(2-3)^3+(1-2)^3+(-1-2)^3=-1-1-27=-29$. The same thing happens when $b=-1$ and $c=1$.

If $b=2$, then $a=-c$ again which leaves with $a$ being either $1$ or $-1$. Either way the first equation doesn't hold. Similar thing happens when $c=2$

Answer (score 1):

Let me try. Note that $2(ab+bc+ca) = a^2+b^2+c^2-(a+b+c)^2 = 2$, then $ab+bc+ca=1$.

We have $$(a-3)^3 + (b-2)^3+(c-2)^3 = 0$$

$$(a-3)^3+(b+c-4)(b^2+c^2+4-2b-2c-bc) = 0$$

$$(a-3)^3 + (-2-a)(6-a^2+4-2(2-a)-(1-a(2-a)))=0$$

$$(a-3)^3-(2+a)(-2a^2+4a+5)=0$$

$$3a^3-9a^2+14a-37=0$$

$$3(a-1)^3+5(a-1)-29=0$$

Solve this equation, you get $a = 2$ is not the root.

If $b=2$, then $a+c=0$, $a^2+c^2 = 2$, so $a=1$, $c=-1$ but it doesn't satisfy the first equation.

Similarly for $c=2$.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a trouble with this question.**

There are non-real solutions for example $a\approx 3.12128,\space b,c\approx -0.56064\pm 1.47835i$.

On the other hand, in $\mathbb R$ as in $\mathbb C$, if $a=2$ then the system 
$$-1+(y-2)^3+(z-2)^3=0\\y^2+z^2=2\\y+z=0$$ is incompatible  and if $b$ or $c$ are equal to $2$ then the system $$(x-3)^3+(y-2)^3=0\\x^2+y^2=2\\x+y=0$$ is incompatible too (i.e. none of the two systems has a solution).

Finally the conclusion is that **there are no real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying the three given equations**

$$\begin{cases}(a-3)^3+(b-2)^3+(c-2)^3=0\\a+b+c=2\\a^2+b^2+c^2=6\end{cases}$$

Consequently there is no reason for this to imply that $a, b$ or $c$ must be equal to $2$.

(*It could be argued that if the given system is incompatible then  $a, b$ or $c$ must be equal to $2$ so that the resulting system is also incompatible.This is not true by doing $a = 4$. I stop here without make $b$ or $c$ distinc of $2$*).

Answer (score 0):

solving the second equation for $c$ we get $$c=2-a-b$$ and inserting this in (I) and (III) we get after some Algebra
$$-9a^2+27a-35-6b^2+12b-3a^2b-3ab^2=0 (*)$$
$$2a^2+2b^2+2ab-4a-4b-2=0$$
solving the last equation for $b$:
$$b_{1,2}=-1/2\,a+1\pm 1/2\,\sqrt {-3\,{a}^{2}+4\,a+8}$$ inserting this in the  equation (*) we get
$$3\,{a}^{3}-9\,{a}^{2}+12\,a-41=0$$ after some Algebra, and the solution is given by $$a \approx3.091040052>2$$ 
the other case is analogously