# Given $a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^3$, show that $a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}+c^{2n+1}=(a+b+c)^{2n+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials

> Assume that $\{a,b,c\} \subset \Bbb R$, $n\in\mathbb N$ and  $a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^3$.
>
> Show that $a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}+c^{2n+1}=(a+b+c)^{2n+1}.$

This is from a list of problems used for training a team for a math olympics. I tried to use known Newton identities and other symmetric polynomial results but without success (perhaps wrong approach). Sorry if it is a duplicate. Hints and answers welcomed.

Comment: Are you really trying to solve those problems or do you just want to know the solutions of the problems. Because it seems you just copied and pasted the second part of your question from your previous question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433186/a-33b-23c-23-0-abc-2-a2b2c2-6-prove-that-at-least-one

Comment: Can you show some effort please so others know where you got stuck on the problem?

Comment: @AnonymousI  Sorry if that bothers you. I´m studying a lot of olympiad training problems that are not trivial for me. I can solve about 70% of them and got stuck on about 30%.That´s why I asked some problems during the last 24 hours.This is the last one. I've just used the same part of the previous question because it is the same thing and saved my typing.

Comment: Oké then. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(a+b+c)^3-a^3-b^3-c^3=\sum_{cyc}(3a^2b+3a^2c+2abc)=3(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$$ and the rest is smooth.

Comment: Would modular arithmatic be applicable???

Comment: @Subhasis Biswas No, of course! Just take $a=-b$.

Comment: AM-GM inequality???

Comment: Sir, I was wondering if I could take a= x(mod k), b= y(mod k) and c= z(mod k)

Comment: @Subhasis Biswas $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Modular arithmatic doesn't hold on reals.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg isn't it $3(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)$ in the last term? BTW what is the meaning of the notation $cyc$ under the summation sign?

Comment: @bluemaster It was typo. I fixed. Thank you! For example: $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2b=a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$. I can write my solution in the full form if you wish.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  Ok, understood. Thanks a lot. It is good to learn new notation.

Comment: No need for the full form.

Comment: @bluemaster You are welcome! Good luck!